# The Marching Tune

Tags: riddle, knowledge, story, chess, history

And a one, and a two, and a three four five six!

Or a one, and a two, and a three four five!

From my home right here,

To the end way down there!

And then I have a choice

Of a one, a two, or a three, or a four!

First named in early 1861,

And born of famous birth!

What name do I have?

And who is the father?

Hint:

> Henry Wadsworth Longfellow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning to this one again, I think @trolley813 was onto something... But the 'name you have' is actually:

> **EXCELSIOR**

As this is the name of:

> A [famous chess problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excelsior_(chess_problem)) set by the great chess player Sam Loyd ('the father') back in 1861.
>
>  The name is taken from a [famous poem](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44631/excelsior-56d223cb4e6fa) by Henry Wadsworth Longfellow (Hint) and literally means 'ever upward'. It is intended to reflect the relentless movement of a pawn from its starting square all the way up the board where it is promoted to a higher-value piece in the course of solving the problem or winning the game. The name 'Excelsior' is now used for any chess problem incorporating such a movement, rather than just the precise set-up used by Loyd in his original poser.

How is this reflected in the puzzle? Pretty much exactly what @trolley813 said:

> The possible movements of a pawn moving across the board to get promotion are described here...

*And a one, and a two, and a three four five six!*
*Or a one, and a two, and a three four five!*
*From my home right here,*
*To the end way down there!*

> A pawn can move from its second-row starting position to the other side in 6 one-step moves, or in 5 moves where the first move covers 2 spaces (as an unmoved pawn is allowed to do). Its 'home' is its starting position, while 'the end way down there' is the other end of the board.

*And then I have a choice*
*Of a one, a two, or a three, or a four!*

> Once a pawn reaches the other side it can be promoted to one of 4 possible pieces: a knight, a bishop, a rook, or a queen.

Hopefully this strategy pays off and the march in question is a march to victory!

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer**

I think the name you have is

> The marching tune is referencing the civil war. The name could be Abraham Lincoln... or possibly, the Confederate States of America.

"And a one, and a two, and a three four five six!"

> The initial Confederacy was established in the Montgomery Convention in February 1861 by seven states (**South Carolina**, **Mississippi**, **Alabama**, **Florida**, **Georgia**, **Louisiana**, adding *Texas* in March before Lincoln's inauguration)  Texas doesn't count here because it was before the inauguration.

"Or a one, and a two, and a three four five!

> --  expanded in May–July 1861 (with **Virginia**, **Arkansas**, **Tennessee**, **North Carolina**), and was disintegrated in April–May 1865. It was formed by delegations from seven slave states of the Lower South that had proclaimed their secession from the Union.  I count **Texas** here.  These eleven states eventually formed the Confederate States of America.

"From my home right here,

To the end way down there!"

> Lincoln lived in Springfield, IL.  The confederacy went as far south as Florida/Texas.

"And then I have a choice

Of a one, a two, or a three, or a four!"

> <s>The Crittenden Compromise was an unsuccessfully proposed to Lincoln, a proposal to permanently enshrine slavery in the United States Constitution, and thereby make it unconstitutional for future congresses to end slavery.  The compromise proposed **four** Congressional resolutions.</s>

"First named him in 1861,"

> On March 4th, 1861, Abraham Lincoln was inaugurated (named) as President of the United States.

Answer (score 2):

Another partial (and probably wrong) answer: Are you

> Alice Liddell (and father being Lewis Carroll)?

Because

> In *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*, she acted as a Queen's pawn. This pawn (as well as any other one) can march across the board in either 5 or 6 moves (depends on the first move being d2-d4 or d2-d3), and in the end she has the choice to promote to 1 of the 4 different pieces (queen, rook, bishop or knight).

Unfortunately

> *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland* were probably started by Carroll in 1862, not 1861, and the answer does not bear any relation to Goodfellow.